# adding to an array using useState using the input value - React

Tags: reactjs, events, use-state

I'm really close to achieving the final goal. My goal is to add X and the name of X is the input's value. I just want a little help that why the function isn't working(I'm sure the method is true). I would appreciate it if you explain it so I can find it myself.

**Function:**

```
const [activityNames, setName] = useState([
    { id: 1, name: 'Feel free to add, edit and delete!' }
]);
const handleSetName = e => {
    const name = {
        id: Math.random() * 10000,
        name: e.target.value
    };
    let names = activityNames.concat(name)
    setName(names);
};
```

**Input:**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Aktivitätsname" value={activityNames.name} />
<button onClick={handleSetName}>
    <i className="fas fa-plus"></i>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to both set the value of the input field properly, and retrieve it properly.

In order to set the value of an input, you also need to have a change listener - put the current value of the input into state, and then use *that* state value inside `handleSetName` instead of `e.target.value`. (The target inside `handleSetName` is the button, which has no value)

```js
const App = () => {
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');
    const [activityNames, setName] = React.useState([
        { id: 1, name: 'Feel free to add, edit and delete!' }
    ]);
    const handleSetName = e => {
        const name = {
            id: Math.random() * 10000,
            name: value
        };
        let names = activityNames.concat(name)
        setName(names);
    };
    return (<div>
        <input placeholder="Aktivitätsname" value={value} onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)} />
        <button onClick={handleSetName}>
            <i className="fas fa-plus"></i>
        </button>
        {JSON.stringify(activityNames)}
    </div>);
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```